# Why Fixed Point Mutiplication is much slower than the Float Point?

Tags: pytorch

Recently, when benchmarking the "matmul" op in Pytorch, and I realize the fixed point(when the dytpe is int) multiplication is much slower, this looks counter intuitive.

```
 n = 128 m = 1024 p = 512 
 t = []
ring_size=(2 ** 64)
for split in np.arange(2,64,2):
    mm =  m // split
    a = torch.randint(-(ring_size // 2), (ring_size - 1) // 2, (n, mm), dtype=torch.int64)
    b = torch.randint(-(ring_size // 2), (ring_size - 1) // 2, (mm, p), dtype=torch.int64)
    init_time = time.time()
    c  = getattr(torch, 'matmul')(a, b)
    t.append(time.time() - init_time)
plt.plot(t)
```

[The following is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkTy7.png)

```
n = 128 m = 1024 p = 512 
t = [] 
for split in np.arange(2,64,2):
            mm =  m // split
            a = torch.tensor(np.random.normal(loc=100, scale=100, size=(n,mm)))
            b = torch.tensor(np.random.normal(loc=100, scale=100, size=(mm,p)))
            init_time = time.time()
            c  = getattr(torch, 'matmul')(a, b)
        t.append(time.time() - init_time) plt.plot(t)
```

[The following is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqQB7.png)

Comment: `int64` has 64 bits. `float` has 32...

Comment: when compare with int32, float is still one order faster..............